# Why does overriding set method only (or getmethod only) from a parent class in Javascript return undefined for it's counter part?[ES6]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was trying to override a Parent Class's set method for a variable (both set and get method implemented) in order to extend certain functionalities in the Child Class. However in doing so, whenever I tried to get the value of variable using get method I got undefined as a returned value.

**Parent Class**

```
//Parent Class
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this._hidden = 10;

    }

    get hidden() {
        return this._hidden;
    }

    set hidden(val) {

        this._hidden = val *10;
    }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
//Child class overriding Parent's set hidden() method
class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    set hidden(val) {
        this._hidden = val *20;
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
let parent = new Parent();
parent.hidden = 10;
console.log("Parent",parent.hidden);

let child = new Child();
child.hidden = 10;
console.log("Child",child.hidden);
```

**OutPut**

[image: Output]

I did get a way around it by making a get method in the child class and having it call the `super.hidden` to get the variable. I want to know why overriding of get and set is not possible in my case or any case? I did a few turn around and tried several cases with the following snippet.

**Example**

```js
//Parent Class
class Parent {
    constructor() {
        this._hidden = 10;

    }
    
    get hidden() {
        return this._hidden;
    }

    set hidden(val) {
        
        this._hidden = val *10;
    }
}

//Child without any overriding
class Child1 extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
//Child class overriding Parent's set hidden() method
class Child2 extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    set hidden(val) {
        this._hidden = val *20;
    }
}

//TO get the job done
class Child3 extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    get hidden() {
        return super.hidden;
    }
    set hidden(val) {
        this._hidden = val *20;
    }
}


let parent = new Parent();
parent.hidden = 10;
console.log("Parent",parent.hidden);


let child1 = new Child1();
child1.hidden = 10;
console.log("Child1",child1.hidden);

let child2 = new Child2();
child2.hidden = 10;
console.log("Child2",child2.hidden);

let child3 = new Child3();
child3.hidden = 10;
console.log("Child3",child3.hidden);
```

Why does this happen and what can I do further?

Comment: Because they are not methods, and not *distinct* methods at all. They are the two parts of *one property*, and you can either overwrite the property or  not overwrite the property.

Comment: if i override the property in the child class won't the property in the Parent class also change? Why does the super.hidden still work?

Comment: No, overriding it does not change the parent property, it just shadows it. `super` is basically magic and starts the property lookup from the parent prototype chain, as if the child prototype did not have the property.